# How do I properly segregate my View and Model in this specific use case

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

So I'm working through a MOOC, Stanford's "Developing iOS 11 Apps with Swift", and in the course the professor highly emphasizes how important it is to separate your View from your Model in the MVC architecture.

One of the assignments is a simple implementation of this game: [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(game)). While I did decouple them, it feels *off*.

I was looking for advice on how to improve the model structure a bit more, without adding in specific view logic. For example, when I started out, instead of using Ints for the fields in my Card model, I used enums like this:

```
enum Symbol {
  case square, circle, triangle
}
```

Which worked somewhat well but the professor advised against doing this because we would be updating the View layer to use different symbols. Here is the code I ended up using, but as I mentioned above it feels off and was wondering how someone more experienced would approach this (The most relevant part is Card.swift but I included everything to illustrate how it was being used):

**Card.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct Card : Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.identifier
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }

    let symbol: Int
    let color: Int
    let shading: Int
    let quantity: Int

    private let identifier: Int
    private static var previousIdentifier = 0
    private static func generateUid() -> Int {
        previousIdentifier += 1
        return previousIdentifier
    }

    init(symbol: Int, color: Int, shading: Int, quantity: Int) {
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.color = color
        self.shading = shading
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.identifier = Card.generateUid()
    }

    static func doesMakeSet(_ cards: [Card]) -> Bool {
        let colors = cards[0].color == cards[1].color && cards[1].color == cards[2].color
        let shading = cards[0].shading == cards[1].shading && cards[1].shading == cards[2].shading
        let quantities = cards[0].quantity == cards[1].quantity && cards[1].quantity == cards[2].quantity
        let symbols = cards[0].symbol == cards[1].symbol && cards[1].symbol == cards[2].symbol
        return colors || shading || quantities || symbols
    }
}
```

**Set.swift**

```
import Foundation

class Set {
    private var deck = [Card]()
    private(set) var board = [Card]() {
        didSet {
            assert(board.count <= 24, "Set.board: board cannot contain more than 24 cards")
        }
    }
    var canDealMoreCards: Bool {
        let matchesThatCanBeRemoved = board.filter { matchedCards.contains($0) }
        let occupiedSpacesOnBoard = board.count - matchesThatCanBeRemoved.count
        let freeSpaces = 24 - occupiedSpacesOnBoard
        let cardsRemaining = deck.count
        return cardsRemaining != 0 && freeSpaces >= 3
    }

    private(set) var selectedCards = [Card]()
    private(set) var matchedCards = [Card]()
    var currentSelectionIsMatch: Bool?

    private(set) var score = 0

    private func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        var newDeck = [Card]()
        let noOfOptions = 1...3
        for quantity in noOfOptions {
            for symbol in noOfOptions {
                for color in noOfOptions {
                    for shading in noOfOptions {
                        newDeck.append(Card(symbol: symbol, color: color, shading: shading, quantity: quantity))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return newDeck
    }

    func dealCards(numberOfCards: Int = 3) {
        if numberOfCards + board.count > 24 {
            board = board.filter { !matchedCards.contains($0) }
        }
        if deck.count >= numberOfCards {
            let range = 0..<numberOfCards
            board.append(contentsOf: deck[range])
            deck.removeSubrange(range)
            assert(board.count <= 24, "Set.dealCards(): there can't be more than 24 cards on the board but \(board.count) are")
        }
    }

    func cardChosen(index: Int) {
        if index > board.count - 1 {
            return
        }
        let card = board[index]
        if matchedCards.contains(card) {
            return
        }
        if selectedCards.count == 3 {
            if Card.doesMakeSet(selectedCards) {
                matchedCards += selectedCards
                selectedCards.removeAll()
                score += 3
                currentSelectionIsMatch = true
                dealCards()
            } else {
                currentSelectionIsMatch = false
                selectedCards.removeAll()
                score -= 5
            }
        } else {
            currentSelectionIsMatch = nil
        }
        if selectedCards.contains(card) {
            selectedCards.remove(at: selectedCards.index(of: card)!)
        } else {
            if !matchedCards.contains(card) {
                selectedCards.append(card)
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        deck = createDeck()
        var shuffled = [Card]()
        for _ in deck.indices {
            let randomIndex = deck.count.arc4random
            shuffled.append(deck.remove(at: randomIndex))
        }
        deck = shuffled
        assert(deck.count == 81)
        dealCards(numberOfCards: 12)
    }
}

extension Int {
    var arc4random: Int {
        if self > 0 {
            return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else if self < 0 {
            return -Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(abs(self))))
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var game = Set()

    @IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var deal3CardsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        updateViewFromModel()
    }

    @IBAction func cardTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let index = cardButtons.index(of: sender) {
            game.cardChosen(index: index)
            updateViewFromModel()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func deal3CardsTouched() {
        game.dealCards()
        updateViewFromModel()
    }

    @IBAction func newGameTouched() {
        game = Set()
        updateViewFromModel()
    }

    func updateViewFromModel() {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(game.score)"
        if let match = game.currentSelectionIsMatch {
            statusLabel.text = match ? "Match!" : "Not a Match!"
        } else {
            statusLabel.text = ""
        }
        cardButtons.forEach {
            $0.hide()
        }
        for index in game.board.indices {
            let text = getAttributedString(forCard: game.board[index])
            cardButtons[index].setAttributedTitle(text, for: UIControlState.normal)
            if game.selectedCards.contains(game.board[index]) {
                cardButtons[index].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
            } else if game.matchedCards.contains(game.board[index]) {
                cardButtons[index].hide()
            } else {
                cardButtons[index].backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
        deal3CardsButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = game.canDealMoreCards
        deal3CardsButton.backgroundColor = game.canDealMoreCards ? #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) : #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

    }

    let symbols = ["▲", "●", "■"]
    let colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)]

    func getAttributedString (forCard card: Card) -> NSAttributedString {
        let symbol = symbols[card.symbol-1]
        let string = String(repeating: symbol, count: card.quantity)
        let color = colors[card.color-1]
        let shading = Shading(rawValue: card.shading)!
        var attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            .strokeWidth: -3,
            .strokeColor: color,
            .foregroundColor: color
        ]
        switch shading {
        case .fill:
            break
        case .open:
            attributes[.foregroundColor] = color.withAlphaComponent(0)
        case .striped:
            attributes[.foregroundColor] = color.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        }

        return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
    }

//    var circle = Symbol.circle

}

// ▲ ● ■

enum Shading: Int {
    case fill = 1, striped, open
}

extension UIButton {
    func hide() {
        self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
        self.setTitle(nil, for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.setAttributedTitle(nil, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: This question would be better off on code review stack exchange

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I wasn't aware that existed. I'll post it there instead.

Comment: All good; best of luck!